# JSF redirect to other page

Tags: jsf, redirect, submit

I have three XHTML pages;

1. index.xhtml
2. page_1.xhtml
3. page_2.xhtml

In the `index.xhtml` page, I have a `commandButton` which sends the user to `page_1.xhtml`.  All this is done in the navigation rule in `faces-config.xml`.

How would I redirect the user to `page_2.xhtml` from the `index.xhtml` using another `commandButton` assuming that both `commandButtons`' actions are linked to a backing Java class?

Comment: why don't you duplicate and change the navigation rules and command buttons ?

Comment: @Daniel it is not working like this too

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? Do you really need to invoke a managed bean action method on page-to-page navigation?

Comment: @BalusC its JSF 2.0.. yes i think so because i have to display different values on each page

Comment: Why do you want to use navigation rules? Are you sure that you aren't focusing too much on JSF 1.x tutorials? Also, do those requests really have to be POST requests rather than GET requests?

Comment: @BalusC Can you tell me how to do it without using navigation rules?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just bind the buttons to different action methods which each return a different outcome.

```html
<h:commandButton value="Go to page 1" action="#{bean.goToPage1}" />
<h:commandButton value="Go to page 2" action="#{bean.goToPage2}" />
```

with

```
public String goToPage1() {
    // ...
    return "page_1";
}

public String goToPage2() {
    // ...
    return "page_2";
}
```

Navigation cases are not necessary. JSF 2.0 supports implicit navigation. The navigation outcome can just be the path/filename of the desired target view. The file extension in the outcome is optional.

If you don't necessarily need to perform any business action on navigation, or you can do it in the (post)constructor of the backing bean of the target page instead, then you can also just put the outcome value in the `action` directly.

```html
<h:commandButton value="Go to page 1" action="page_1" />
<h:commandButton value="Go to page 2" action="page_2" />
```

A `<h:commandButton>` will however not perform a redirect, but a forward. The enduser won't see the URL being changed in the browser address bar. The target page isn't bookmarkable. If you can, I'd suggest to use `<h:button>` instead.

```html
<h:button value="Go to page 1" outcome="page_1" />
<h:button value="Go to page 2" outcome="page_2" />
```

Or if you *really* need to invoke a business action, but would like to perform a real redirect, then append `faces-redirect=true` as query string to the outcome value.

```
public String goToPage1() {
    // ...
    return "page_1?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String goToPage2() {
    // ...
    return "page_2?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this, in any part of your code to be redirected to "example.xhtml"

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext();
try {
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath()
            + "/faces/jsf/example.xhtml");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add two navigation cases as shown below. In the action methods, return outcomes corresponding to the buttons.

```
            <navigation-rule>
                <from-view-id>index.html</from-view-id>
                <navigation-case>
                    <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
                    <to-view-id>page_1.xhtml</to-view-id>
                </navigation-case>
                <navigation-case>
                    <from-outcome>page2</from-outcome>
                    <to-view-id>page_2.xhtml</to-view-id>
                </navigation-case>
            </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: how would you add re-direct in this scenario

Comment: I have the same issue with `?faces-redirect=true` being added to the backing bean's `return "some_view?faces-redirect=true";` it gives me the missing navigation rule message.

Comment: @AjaySharma within a `<navigation-case>` block you can add the self closing tag `<redirect />`