# Update the page with command bouton primefaces

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to get the value of the input Textarea and show it in the same page by clicking on the command button "compiler " 
however i don't get any result ! and the contnet is only shown when I update with the browser updater 
Sh How do I upate the page and the managed beans to show the content of a primefaces textarea in the same page
this is the code:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="520" header="Code à executer" resizable="true" >
    <h:form id="moncode">
 <p:inputTextarea id="mycode" value="#{fichier.code}" rows="17" cols="50" /> 
 <p:commandButton value="compiler" id="btn3"  action="guest.xhtml"   styleClass="myButtonClass" />
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="east" size="550" header="Resultat d'execution" resizable="true" >
   <h:outputText value="#{fichier.code}" /> 
</p:layoutUnit>


             <p:layoutUnit position="south"  >
```

my application is about compiling a given code: I write a code and then I executed with the button "compiler" so a file will be created however the file is always created with "null" and I think because the var "code" is not yet set in the managed bean that why I want to update the page so the managed bean ill be set here is compile:
    ` 
     private String code;
    private String error;

```
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}
 public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

 public void compile() throws IOException {
 File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Rad1\\test.c");
 PrintWriter ecrivain;  
 ecrivain = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(file))); 
      ecrivain.println(code);  
  ecrivain.close();
```

`

Comment: Specify your problem/requirement more clearly. What's not working as you intended? What you intended? What errors are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want: either by using a synchronous submit of a form with a subsequesnt postback, or by sending an AJAX request to partially update necessary parts of the page.

### Synchronous submit

```
<p:inputTextarea id="mycode" value="#{fichier.code}" rows="17" cols="50" /> 
<p:commandButton value="compiler" id="btn3" action="#{fichier.action}" styleClass="myButtonClass" ajax="false" />
<h:outputText id="upd" value="#{fichier.code}" />
```

with action method

```
public String action() {
    //do business job
    return null;
}
```

This way a fields will be refreshed by making a postback. Don't forget that the bean `Fichier` must be view scoped. Note the `ajax="false"` attribute of `<p:commandButton>`.

### AJAX call

```
<p:inputTextarea id="mycode" value="#{fichier.code}" rows="17" cols="50" /> 
<p:commandButton value="compiler" id="btn3" action="#{fichier.action}" styleClass="myButtonClass" update="upd" />
<h:outputText id="upd" value="#{fichier.code}" />
```

with the same action method

```
public String action() {
    //do business job
    return null;
}
```

This way only the contents of `<h:outputText>` will be updated after AJAX call is finished. Don't forget that the bean `Fichier` should also be view scoped. Note that `id` attribute of `<h:outputText>` must be specified.

Comment: thank you @skuntsel but its not quit what i wanted , i have edited my post to clear that

Comment: i had to add another botton to refresh the input text so that it is  set in the managed bean and then use it in the compiling function

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't call the action itself. Your action forwards to a certain page. There is no race condition or syncronization problems in a JSF action betwwen setting the properties and the action itself. I recommend you to read [JSF life cycles tutorial by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) Aplly request values phase run before the action.

Try to call action on command Button.

```
<p:commandButton value="compiler" id="btn3"  action="#{fichier.compile}" update="outputCode"  styleClass="myButtonClass" />
```

Add an id attribute to your output panel and specify it in the action button.

```
<p:layoutUnit id="outputCode" position="east" size="550" header="Resultat d'execution" resizable="true" >
   <h:outputText value="#{fichier.code}" /> 
</p:layoutUnit>
```

P.S. It is also good to read [this BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463295/jsf-redirect-to-other-page) for better understanding of actions, Ajax/non Ajax request etc.

Comment: OP's code would do a forward, not a redirect. And if you look closely, it's an AJAX command button.

Comment: OK. My code also do a ajax request and i edit my "redirects" word to "forwards"