# JSF registration redirect doesn't work

Tags: jsf

I have registration.xhtml with button:

---

`<h:button value="Register" action="#{registrationBean.saveUser}" ajax="false"></h:button>`

registrationBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "registrationBean")
@SessionScoped
public class RegistrationBean {
...     
public String saveUser() {
    personService.savePerson(persons);
    return "user/user";
}
```

And it doesn't work. [Link on git](https://github.com/person2713/PaymentCard/tree/vv)

Please help

Comment: Do you want to go to another page when you finish registration ?!?

Comment: This one could help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463295/jsf-redirect-to-other-page